# Executing a Command when a ListView is DoubleClicked. (WPF - MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I am having some difficulties binding a command (ICommand) to the MouseBinding of a ListView.
I used this piece of XAML code to test the different mouse gestures:

```
<ListView.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding OpenSOACommand}" Gesture="LeftClick" />
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding OpenSOACommand}" Gesture="MiddleClick" />
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding OpenSOACommand}" Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" />
</ListView.InputBindings>
```

The LeftClick and LeftDoubleClick gestures aren't triggered, yet the MiddleClick mouse binding works perfect (I have tested the mouse bindings one at a time as well...).

Is there a difference in the way the LeftDoubleClick and MiddleClick Gesture is handled? And if there is, how can I bind my ICommand to the LeftDoubleClick gesture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `Click` event for the ListView is marking the event as handled. Try using `PreviewLeftClick` and `PreviewLeftDoubleClick` instead

EDIT

Since `MouseBindings` does not contain a `PreviewLeftClick` or `PreviewLeftDoubleClick`, try using the `AttachedCommandBehavior` code found [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/) which allows you to attach a `Command` to just about any `Event`

For example,

```
<ListView local:CommandBehavior.Event="PreviewMouseDown" 
          local:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding OpenSOACommand}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your ListViewItems of your ListView will swallow your LeftClick events and convert them into nice SelectionChanged events. Since the ListViewItems will not respond to MiddleClick, this will work as expected.

You might want to get 'in front' of this click by handling the matching Preview equivalent of the event.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnItemDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And invoke the command in the handler:

```
private void OnItemDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     OpenSOACommand.Execute(null, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go, although I don't realy want to handle events in my code behind when I could bind my commands directly in the XAML itself...

Comment: I admit, its ugly.. But you cannot change the behaviour that your ListView swallows your click events before your command can be handled.